# What is the star I see under the question down arrow?

Tags: support

I presume it is some kind of mechanism to help me keep track of things for later revisiting.  I see I can click to change the state of the star.  But I don't think star is the right name for this thing, as I can't find "star" in the help or Meta.  I've looked in my profile too.

I am most interested in going back to the questions that I have clicked the star in earlier.

[image: screen shot with star highlighted]

Answer (score 6):

The star indicates things that are called **favourites** ("or **favorites**") in the documentation and interface.

The help guide explains how to search within your favorites: https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Comment: I like bmike's edit;  should I upvote the post, even though I created it myself?

Comment: You can't upvote your own post even if you try!

Comment: OK.  I'll explore more and ask less, I suppose.